# Install JDK17 on raspberrypi

Tags: raspberry-pi, openjdk

I am trying to install JDK17 on raspberrypi but it keeps on telling me

```
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-17-jdk
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-17-jdk
```

I even tried zulu jdk using https://docs.azul.com/core/install/debian but it stills says the same .

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo apt install zulu17-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zulu17-jdk
```

My Raspberry pi config is

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Has anyone ever tried to successfully install jdk17 . I am installing jdk17 as its a preq for neo4j .

Comment: What does `uname -m` show? Would it be at all possible for you to upgrade to Raspbian 11 or later?

Comment: It shows armv7l

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian 10 only has OpenJDK 11; to install the packaged version of OpenJDK 17 on Raspbian, you should upgrade to Raspbian 11.

You *can* install a third-party version of OpenJDK 17 on Raspbian 10. The reason you weren’t able to install Zulu is that packages aren’t provided for 32-bit ARM systems; to install Zulu, you’d have to [download the relevant tarball](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-17-lts&os=linux&architecture=arm-32-bit-hf&package=jdk#zulu) and install it manually.